# File reader freezing my program

Tags: c#, file, methods, datagridview, freeze

I am stuck not being able to determine why my program is freezing when running the following method:

```
String fileName = "Drops.de";
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        String npcName;
        string npcID;
        string itemID;
        string itemAmount;
        string itemRarity;
        string itemName;

        while(!streamReader.EndOfStream){
            string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            //start of block
            if(line.StartsWith("[")){
                npcName = line.TrimStart('[');
                npcName = npcName.TrimEnd(']');
                while(npcName == button1.Text){    
                while(!line.StartsWith("[/")){
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    String[] s = line.Split(' ');
                    npcID = (s[0]);
                    itemName = (s[1]);
                    itemID = (s[2]);
                    itemAmount = (s[3]);
                    itemRarity = (s[4]);
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(itemName, itemID, itemAmount, itemRarity);
                    /*
                    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
                    row.Cells[0].Value = itemName;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = itemID;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = itemAmount;
                    row.Cells[3].Value = itemRarity;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);*/
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
               //MessageBox.Show(npcName);
                }
                }

            }
        }
        streamReader.Close();
    }
```

I have the suspicion it has something to do with the 'while' loop. However I am most likely wrong. I am rather new to programming so it is probably something obvious :p.

Anyway all help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Well, have you tried using the debugger? What exactly do you mean by "freeze"? If you're doing all of this on the UI thread then your UI *will* freeze until the loop has finished - but are you saying it actually freezes permanently?

Comment: I just tried the debugger, it doesn't shed further light on the issue. I think you may be correct with your looping theory, as what I mean by freezing is that the UI becomes unresponsive, and yes it is on the UI thread, but the loop shouldn't take long at all to finish as it was just a few lines. I think I am just reading the logic wrong and the program is stuck in a permanent loop, I'm not sure where I have gone wrong though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will you ever exit this loop `while(npcName == button1.Text){`? :-)